# How can I save text from an Edittext without loosing the features of the text like Bold, Italic etc. in Android

Tags: android

All I am trying to do is to get the text from the Edittext which is having the features like bold and italic and saving it in a text file but when I read it back and display it, the features are lost, they don't show. How can I maintain the rich features by saving the text in a text file or any.

Comment: you need to get EditText text as HTML ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Html.toHtml()` to convert the `Editable` that you get back from `getText()` on an `EditText` to an HTML representation. Then, later on, you can use `Html.fromHtml()` to convert the HTML back into something that can be used in an `EditText`. `toHtml()` and `fromHtml()` do not handle every possible span used by `EditText`, but it should handle the basics like bold and italics.

Comment: Is there any file format that could save the text as it is in EditText as a text file doesn't support it.

Comment: @user1878746: Text files definitely support HTML. The Web page that you are viewing is text.