# Reading text file keeping previous format

Tags: android, android-studio, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Im making a simple network app and want to load the chat log on start up, this works fine but it formats the text as one line

Writing to file

```
CharSequence cs = tv.getText ();
final String str = cs + "\r\n" + s;
//Write to text file
try {
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("Chat Log", Context.MODE_APPEND);
fos.write(s.getBytes());
fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}



}
catch (IOException e1)
{

e1.printStackTrace();
}
//close the socket
socket.close();
```

Reading Text

```
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
try {
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
openFileInput("Chat Log")));
String inputString;
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\r\n");
tv.append(inputString);
}

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Current Result 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hodp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save formatting using [Html.toHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml(android.text.Spanned)) and [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)).

Something along the lines of:

```
String htmlFormatted = Html.toHtml(tv.getText());
// .. save to file ..
```

Then:

```
Spanned htmlFormatted = Html.fromHtml(chatLog);
tv.setText(htmlFormatted);
```

See these similar questions:

- [Saving the text styling applied to text using setSpan()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632132/saving-the-text-styling-applied-to-text-using-setspan/17632176#17632176)
- [How can I save text from an Edittext without loosing the features of the text like Bold, Italic etc. in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726857/how-can-i-save-text-from-an-edittext-without-loosing-the-features-of-the-text-li/13727063#13727063)

Comment: @josh-reilly Please accept the answer or let me know if it wasn't helpful.